Kafka Streams and Spring Batch Conflict - "Job name must be specified" despite spring.batch.job.enabled: false
I have a Spring Boot application where I am using Kafka Streams (KStream and GlobalKTable) along with a Spring Batch job. Despite setting spring.batch.job.enabled: false, I keep encountering the following error:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Job name must be specified in case of multiple jobs

GlobalKTableConfig: Creates a GlobalKTable using Kafka Streams:
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class GlobalKTableConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.streams.properties.store-name}")
    private String storeName;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.streams.properties.schema.registry.url-config}")
    private String schemaRegistryUrl;

    @Value("${kafka.topic.name}")
    private String topic;

    @Value("${global-kafka-streams.application-id}")
    private String globalTableAppId;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.streams.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean(name = "globalKTableStreamsConfig")
    public KafkaStreamsConfiguration globalKTableStreamsConfig() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, globalTableAppId);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
        return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
    }

    @Bean(name = "globalKTableStreamsBuilder")
    public StreamsBuilderFactoryBean globalKTableStreamsBuilder(
        @Qualifier("globalKTableStreamsConfig") KafkaStreamsConfiguration globalKTableStreamsConfig) {
        return new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(globalKTableStreamsConfig, new CleanupConfig(true, true));
    }

    @Bean
    public GlobalKTable<String, GenericRecord> createGlobalKTable(
        @Qualifier("globalKTableStreamsBuilder") StreamsBuilderFactoryBean globalKTableStreamsBuilderFactoryBean) throws Exception {

        StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = globalKTableStreamsBuilderFactoryBean.getObject();//5

        Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryUrl);
        final Serde<GenericRecord> valueGenericAvroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
        valueGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);

        return streamsBuilder.globalTable(ediLegTopic,
            Materialized.<String, GenericRecord, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(storeName + "-global")
                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                .withValueSerde(valueGenericAvroSerde));
    }
}

KStreamsConfig: Creates a KStream and joins it with the GlobalKTable:
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@DependsOn("createGlobalKTable")
public class KStreamsConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.topic.name}")
    private String topic;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.streams.application-id}")
    private String applicationId;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.streams.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.streams.properties.schema.registry.url-config}")
    private String schemaRegistryUrl;

    @Value("${kstream-kafka-streams.application-id}")
    private String kStreamAppId;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.streams.properties.store-name}")
    private String storeName;

    @Bean(name = "kafkaStreamsConfig")
    public KafkaStreamsConfiguration kafkaStreamsConfig() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, kStreamAppId);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
        return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
    }

    @Bean(name = "kStreamBuilder")
    public StreamsBuilderFactoryBean kStreamBuilder(
        @Qualifier("kafkaStreamsConfig") KafkaStreamsConfiguration config) {
        return new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(config, new CleanupConfig(true, true));
    }

    @Bean
    public KStream<String, GenericRecord> createKStream(@Qualifier("kStreamBuilder") StreamsBuilder kStreamBuilder,
                                                        @Qualifier("createGlobalKTable") GlobalKTable<String, GenericRecord> globalKTable) {
        Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryUrl);
        final Serde<GenericRecord> valueGenericAvroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
        valueGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);

        KStream<String, GenericRecord> kStream = kStreamBuilder.stream(ediLegTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), valueGenericAvroSerde));

        KStream<String, GenericRecord> joinedStream = kStream.leftJoin(globalKTable,
            (key, value) -> key,
            (streamValue, tableValue) -> {
                if (tableValue != null) {
                    return null;
                }
                return streamValue;
            });

        processJoinedStream(joinedStream);

        return joinedStream;
    }


    private void processJoinedStream(KStream<String, GenericRecord> joinedStream) {
        joinedStream.foreach((key, value) -> {
            // processing logic here
        });
    }
}

syncBatchConfiguration: Defines a Spring Batch job:
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class syncBatchConfiguration {


    public syncBatchConfiguration(
       // configuration
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<AEntity> itemReader(
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<AEntity,BEntity> itemProcessor() {     
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<AEntity> itemWriter() {
        RepositoryItemWriter<AEntity> itemWriter = new RepositoryItemWriter<>();
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        log.info("Creating ThreadPoolTaskExecutor...");
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    protected Step process(JobRepository jobRepository,
        //implement step 
    }

    @Bean
    public Job processJob(JobRepository jobRepository, Step processStep) {
       //implement job
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutorJobLauncher asyncJobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
        TaskExecutorJobLauncher jobLauncher = new TaskExecutorJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }
}

I've already tried using @DependsOn, @Primary, and exclude = {BatchAutoConfiguration.class}, but none of them solve the issue. When I remove the @Configuration annotation from syncBatchConfiguration, the application works fine.
I want Kafka Streams (KStream and GlobalKTable) to work correctly alongside the Spring Batch job without conflicts. How can I resolve this conflict and prevent Spring Batch from interfering with Kafka Stream.
